# Is Enum as a Generic Type a valid approach in Dart?

Tags: dart, enums

I find myself facing a situation involving enum abstraction in Dart. Not sure to labeled this as abstraction in first place. here is my situation:

```
class Tool {
final Enum metrics;
}

enum Gram {kg, g}
enum Meter {km, m}
```

i want this `Tool` can retrieve enum feature using a getter like .name.

Furthermore, what distinguishes the above approach from the following one using generics in Dart?

```
class Tool<T extends Enum>{
final T metrics;
}
```

As a newcomer to this concept, could someone provide insights and guidance? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your direct question, the `final Enum metrics` vs `final T metrics` with `<T extends Enum>`, the difference is how *outside* code can use the class.
Inside the class itself, the type variable `T` isn't bound when the code is type-checked, so all it can know is that `metrics` is an `Enum`.
Code outside of the class will have a type like `Tool<Gram>`, in which case they can tell that `thatObject.metrics` has stype `Gram`, not just `Enum`.

That mainly matters if there is something to use that information for.

I'd rather introduce a subtype for metrics, not just use `Enum` directly. There can be many `enum` declarations that are not metrics, and the type would allow those as well.

Maybe add some more properties to the metric type to make it *useful*.

```dart
import "dart:math" as math;

mixin Metric<M extends Metric<M>> on Enum {
  /// Name of the unit for display.
  String get name => EnumName(this).name;

  /// The standard unit of this metric.
  ///
  /// Will have a [scale] of 0.  
  M get standardUnit;

  /// The power of 10 of the [standardUnit] that this unit represents.
  int get scale;

  /// Creates a measurement of this type.
  Measure<M> call(num value) => Measure(value, this);

  String toString() => name;
}

/// A unit of mass or weight.
enum Weight with Metric<Weight> {
  ug(-6),
  mg(-3),
  g(0),
  kg(3);

  final int scale;

  const Weight(this.scale);
  Weight get standardUnit => g;
}

/// A unit of length.
enum Length with Metric<Length> {
  m(0),
  km(3),
  cm(-2),
  mm(-3),
  nm(-6);

  final int scale;

  const Length(this.scale);
  Length get standardUnit => m;
}

class Measure<M extends Metric<M>> {
  final num value;
  final Metric<M> unit;
  Measure(this.value, this.unit);

  Measure<M> normalize() => unit.scale == 0 ? this :
      Measure<M>(value * math.pow(10, unit.scale), unit.standardUnit);

  Measure<M> operator +(Measure<M> other) {
    var scaleDelta = other.unit.scale - unit.scale;
    return Measure<M>(value + other.value * math.pow(10, scaleDelta), unit);
  }
  Measure<M> operator -(Measure<M> other) {
    var scaleDelta = other.unit.scale - unit.scale;
    return Measure<M>(value - other.value * math.pow(10, scaleDelta), unit);
  }
  Measure<M> to(M otherUnit) => unit.scale == otherUnit.scale
      ? this
      : Measure<M>(
          value * math.pow(10, unit.scale - otherUnit.scale), otherUnit);

  String toString() => "$value $unit";
}

void main() {
  print(Length.m(2) + Length.km(1));
  print(Length.m(42).to(Length.cm));
}
```

This allows you to do
``
However, there is nothing in this that *requires* the metrics to be `enum`s.

If you want to define your own `var pentaMeter = Meter(5);` for 10^5 meters, there is no reason to stop you, so I'd probably just make the metrics normal classes:

```dart
abstract base class Metric<M extends Metric<M>> {
  /// Name of the unit for display.
  final String name;

  /// The power of 10 of the [standardUnit] that this unit represents.
  final int scale;

  /// The standard unit of this metric.
  ///
  /// Will have a [scale] of 0.  
  M get standardUnit;

  const Metric(this.name, this.scale);
  
  /// Creates a measurement of this type.
  Measure<M> call(num value) => Measure<M>(value, this);
  
  String toString() => name;
}

/// A unit of mass or weight.
final class Weight extends Metric<Weight> {
  static const g = Weight("g", 0),
      ug = Weight("ug", -6),
      mg = Weight("mg", -3),
      kg = Weight("kg", 3);

  const Weight(super.name, super.scale);

  Weight get standardUnit => g;
}

/// A unit of length.
final class Length extends Metric<Length> {
  static const m = Length("m", 0),
      km = Length("km", 3),
      cm = Length("cm", -2),
      mm = Length("mm", -3),
      nm = Length("nm", -6);

  const Length(super.name, super.scale);
  
  Length get standardUnit => m;
}
```

and then use it the same way, but not care whether it's an enum or not.

And you can do `var pm = Length("pm", 5);` and use it as just another notation for length.

(Do be aware that an attempt to capture "units" in general tend to quickly get into *combinations* of units, like m/s or kg/m<sup>2</sup>. Not a task to be taken likely.)